# Is there a way to filter many-to-many filters in Django using fields from the intermediate table?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have 3 models in Django.

`Group`, `Membership` and `User`.

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    permissions = JSONField(max_length=4096, default=list)

class Membership(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='memberships')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='memberships')
    expires_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    valid = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class User(models.Model):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, through=Membership)
    last_seen = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I was wondering how I could "filter" the many-to-many on user to only retrieve group objects from memberships where `expires_at` is either greater than now or null. Thank you!

Comment: The question isn't clear. What are you trying to achieve? On which table and field do you want to apply the filter?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear enough, I have since updated my question to make it easier. Sincerest apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for expires at less than now, but I have written the query for expires at greater than now as per your request

1. Use Q for querying on "OR". So your filter query will be

```
from django.db.models import Q
Q(expires_at__gt=now) | Q(expires_at__isnull=True)
```

2. You want to filter memberships for a certain user. So your query boils down to

```
Membership.objects.filter(user=user).filter(Q(expires_at__gt=now) | Q(expires_at__isnull=True))
```

3. Get all group ids for your query

```
Membership.objects.filter(user=user).filter(Q(expires_at__gt=now) | Q(expires_at__isnull=True)).values_list('group_id', flat=True)
```

4. Get all relevant groups

```
queryset = Membership.objects.filter(user=user).filter(Q(expires_at__gt=now) | Q(expires_at__isnull=True)).values_list('group_id', flat=True)

result = Group.objects.filter(id__in=queryset)
```

Though I think there must be a better solution for step 4, but this is fine too.

If you are just looking for group names, then this is enough

```
result = Membership.objects.filter(user=user).filter(Q(expires_at__gt=now) | Q(expires_at__isnull=True)).values_list('group__name', flat=True)
```